# How can I use Hibernate Validation with my Richfaces project?

Tags: hibernate, validation, jsf, richfaces

I am using Richfaces 3.3.3, JSF 1.2, and JBoss Tools 3.1. I believe this has Hibernate Validator 4.1.

I am trying to use Hibernate annotation validation in conjunction with the .  If I use the required=true attribute of the form components, then the validation messages are printed as expected.  However none of the hibernate validators print. The console says that a validator is being instantiated but no messages are printed.

Are these versions compatible?
What coule be wrong?
I followed this example:  [usage](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html/rich_ajaxValidator.html#d0e9703)

EDIT: When I run the page and enter some info, onblur I get this info on the console (using Eclipse).

```
11:39:13,004 INFO  [org.hibernate.validator.util.Version] Hibernate Validator 4.1.0.Final
11:39:13,036 INFO  [org.hibernate.validator.engine.resolver.DefaultTraversableResolver] Instantiated an instance of org.hibernate.validator.engine.resolver.JPATraversableResolver.
11:39:13,153 INFO  [org.hibernate.validator.Version] Hibernate Validator 3.1.0.GA
11:39:13,168 INFO  [org.hibernate.annotations.common.Version] Hibernate Commons Annotations 3.2.0.Final
```

To me that means its firing, just not displaying the message. Any suggestions with this new info in mind?

Answer (score 0):

This should help: [RichFaces with Hibernate Validator](http://mkblog.exadel.com/2009/12/richfaces-with-hibernate-validator/)

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer. Unfortunately I found that link in searching on my own and it wasn't able to help. I appreciate the help though.

Comment: Try Hibernate Validator 3.1, I think that's what I used in my blog. Using required attribute works because that's JSF validation being invoked.

Comment: Hmm...ok it's worth a shot. I'll go try that now.  In the meantime, I tried adding the 4.1 libraries to my project and it broke saying the view could not be restored. I'm not entirely sure what that means (I'm learning this as I go). Is that an issue?  Are there conflicting versions? I ask the latter because if I don't add any hibernate valdator libraries, it still tries to instantiate a validator so it seems like its included somehow.

Comment: I've also added some new info to the question. I appreciate any help you can give. I didn't realize that was actually your tutorial. I wanted to tell you it was actually very helpful, it just hasn't helped me negotiate this problem :-)

Comment: When the view couldn't be restored, just close all browser windows and restart the server.